# Let's make the hot network questions icons clickable

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, sidebar

I would like to see the icons in the 'Hot Network Questions' right panel clickable, leading to the homepage of the site where the question comes from.

It would make it more comfortable to switch to the site when you want rather to visit it than to see that specific "hot" question.

[image]

Comment: Related: [whatever you do, site icon behavior should be consistent between the community bulletin and the Hot Questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234628/).

Comment: Removed tags that are not really relevant, as the request is for the hot questions sidebar. :)

Comment: Just to be clear, the thinking one would have when using this is "*Oh yeah, I forgot to go see what's new on that site, glad I saw this question, but it doesn't really interest me, I'd rather just go to the site instead*"?

Comment: @TimPost Exactly! It often simply reminds me of sites I haven't visited for a while :)

Comment: This seems like a no-brainer that shouldn't take much effort to implement. I can't see any reason as to why it isn't already implemented.

Answer (score 12):

Until this gets implemented you can use the following script:

```
/*global $:true, window:true */
(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#hot-network-questions ul li').each(
        function () {
            var li = $(this),
                href = li.find('a').prop('href'),
                chars_to_skip = 9; // skips over https://
            li.find('div').wrap(
                $('<a></a>')
                    .prop('href', href.substr(0, href.indexOf('/', chars_to_skip)))
                    .prop('target', '_blank')
                    .css('width','auto')
            ).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }
    );
}());
```

that gets easy transformed in a Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey script.

This code finds the hot network questions div on the page and iterates over the `li` tags. The `div` that holds the icon gets wrapped in an `a` anchor tag which gets its href from the existing anchor tag href attribute in the `li` but only the protocol and hostname.

#### html structure (simplified) before script runs

```
<li>
    <div title="foo" class="favicon favicon-math"></div>
    <a href="http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100090/">
        FooBar
    </a>
</li>
```

#### html structure after script runs

```
<li>
    <a href="http://math.stackexchange.com" target="_blank" style="width:auto">
        <div title="foo" class="favicon favicon-math"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100090/">
        FooBar
    </a>
</li>
```